# Argument matching with Mockito and Scalatest

Tags: scala, junit, mockito, scalatest

I'm trying to use mockito with scalatest however my mock is always returning null. Its a simple test however the call to post is not returning the object i expect (someObj3) instead it returns null. Any ideas what is happening? Also is there an equivalent API in Scala which would allow me to pass any argument of a particular class or type when creating the expectation?

```
@Test def mockTestt = {
 var mock:Someclass = Mockito.mock(classOf[Someclass]);
 systemUnderTest.setSomeClass(mock)

 when(mock.post(someObj1,someObj2))
        .thenReturn(someObj3) 

 var status:String = systemUnderTest.isOpen(someObj1, someObj2)
 Assert.assertTrue(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Enabled"))
```

}

Comment: Where/how do you define `someObj3`?  Without that definition it would probably be working and returning the null for not defining/setting `someObj3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the mock itself is not `null`, but rather you did not stub or mock the members of that mock that you're using after it's created.

If you can switch to Specs2, you'll find the DSL it provides for Mockito is vastly easier to deal with. You'll still need to stub / mock all the nested / subsidiary members of the mocks, but your code will be far less noisy and verbose if you do.

Comment: yes the mock was doing its job however the arguments i used did not pass the equality test. I have been able resolve now. Thanks